# call user friend in facebook SDK via JQuery load and Had some Error

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, jquery, codeigniter-2

i want to show friends list with FQL in facebook application with Jquery ajax Load. I have succes to load user friends list but sometimes had some error like this :
Fatal Error : Uncaught OAuthException: An Active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
How can I handle this Error?

here's my javascrpit code and I use CodeIgniter :

> $('#boyslist').load('friendslist/boyslist', function()
>   {     //some callback script });
>
> $('#girlslist').load('friendslist/girlslist',
>   function() {  //some callback script });

This My Controller :

```
function boyslist($offset=0) {
    $data['friend_record'] = $this->Facebook_model->getfriendslist('male', 0);
    $data['boy_count']    = $this->Facebook_model->countAllFriends('male');
    $data['gender']        = 'male';
    $this->load->view('pages/v_malelist', $data);
}

function girlslist($offset=0) {
    $data['friend_record'] = $this->Facebook_model->getfriendslist('female', 0);
    $data['girl_count']    = $this->Facebook_model->countAllFriends('female');
    $data['gender']        = 'female';
    $this->load->view('pages/v_femalelist', $data);
}
```

This is My Model :

```
function getfriendslist($gender, $offset) {
    $pos = 0 + $offset;
    $limit = 10;
    return $this->facebook->api(
            array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' =>
                " SELECT uid, name, pic, sex, relationship_status FROM user 
                    WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) and sex='".$gender."' order by name limit ".$pos.", ".$limit." " )
            );
}
```

Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using an earlier version of facebook sdk, so it looks like the current sdk on github introduced the issue.

My php app on Heroku uses the latest FB sdk, and it started failing. Luckily, I had an approx. 1 month old sdk that I used on my local server, and this still works even when from Heroku.

The issue seems to occur only with AJAX loading from the client.